# Exempt resource to use its own integration while others to use AWS API GW Proxy Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am integrating AWS API GW to set of APIs exposed through AWS ALB. Couple of these API endpoints should be exposed without authorisation while all others should go through authoriser. How could I do that using API GW HTTP_PROXY integration?

I tried to achieve this by setting up two resources in API GW. One base resource with ANY /{proxy+} attached to Cognito Authoriser and another resource GET /user-ms/health without any authoriser.

However, it never hit GET /user-ms/health API configure without authoriser. Always, it goes through {+proxy} integration and giving me 401 error. Is there a way that I can set a weight of order with API resources. Otherwise only option I am left with is not to use any proxy integration but integrate each operation separately. Isn't it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you set ANY base resource then of course everything will be directed there. If you want to avoid handing authorization in your code then you might want to create an ANY resource with the same proxy integration with the path as /private and then create others in the root that are public or to follow the same pattern under /public.

Comment: Thanks Gergely for the response, Yes, that is something possible. I didn't go on that path since it makes the URL bit verbose. Before going on any of these paths, thought of checking whether there is a weighted route option that I have missed in AWS documentation.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way to achieve this without touching your application code.